# Accessing Windows Mobile device Storage Card from Java?

Tags: java, windows-mobile

I'd like to be able to access the contents of my Storage Card which is in my Windows Mobile device. Normally, I'd just remove the card and shove it in a card reader, but its encrypted (and thus, locked to my WM device).

Is there an API or some sort of framework allowing read/write access to the Storage Card (while PDA is docked to PC)?

Reason is: I'm sick of having to create playlists for each album every time I upload to it. I'd like to automate this process.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the PDA is connected to the PC you can use [RAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa458022.aspx) to access files, registry etc on a Windows Mobile device, but I don't know of a Java interface to it. Should be a piece of cake with JNI though... :-)

Answer (score 2):

RAPI (Remote API) is used for accessing the WM device from the desktop, and can be used to access files.
See [RAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa458022.aspx) and [CeCreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa458360.aspx), or [this tutorial on RAPI](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Pocket+pc+network+programming/Chapter+9.+Desktop+Synchronization/Remote+API+RAPI/).
You can point it to files on the storage card by the "\Storage Card\" path.

But, as you notice, this is a C++ API... I'm not aware of any RAPI wrappers for Java, unfortunately.